# LeetCode Python 3 vs Python 3 in other environments

Tags: python, python-3.x

My question is what is List defined as to allow it to be used in the parameters and virtually be ignored.

On LeetCode Python3 this will return grid

```
class Solution:
    def uniquePathsIII(self, grid: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        return gird
```

But on other Python3 environments it will return

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
class Solution:
  File "main.py", line 2, in Solution
    def uniquePathsIII(self, grid: List[List[int]]) -> int:
NameError: name 'List' is not defined
```

I want to test code for LeetCode in another environment and I think this is near equivalent of the LeetCode test. Probably works just as well.

```
class Solution:
    def uniquePathsIII(self, grid: [[int]]) -> int:
        return grid
fin = Solution()
print(fin.uniquePathsIII([[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,2,-1]]))
```

But I am still wondering why List is allowed in the parameters on LeetCode

Comment: Those are type annotations. They do nothing to your actual code, they're just there to hint at the type that that variable should be (unless your interpreter pays attention to them, like mypy). `List` is `typing.List` See https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: `typing.List` is an older approach to this. In more recent versions of Python you can just use `list` itself in type annotations: `list[list[int]]`.

Comment: You need to do `from typing import List` in your other environment. If you don't need to do that on Leetcode, they're doing it by default for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your code example you wrote:

```
def uniquePathsIII(self, grid: [[int]]) -> int:
        return grid
```

However, this is not correct syntax. Type annotations in the newest versions of python are used like this:

```
def uniquePathsIII(self, grid: list[list[int]]) -> int:
        return grid
```

For more information I recommend watching this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMXsIX3PZ5w

Also, make sure you are using a recent version of Python (3.9+)